# Split into file with first column Name

Tags: shell-script, scripting, csv, split

I have this CSV file:

```
"Product ID";"Product Name";"Price";"Description";
"11;"Example";"200";"Descripcion here...";
"21;"Example2";"300";"Some here...";
```

I want to split it line by line and save them into the file with the name of first column.

Example:

```
11.csv {"11;"Example";"200";"Descripcion here...";}
21.csv {"21;"Example2";"300";"Some here...";}
```

I use this command:

```
 $ split -l 1 file.txt new
```

But this create  newa ,newb,newc,newd, etc!?

Comment: Could this be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26743791/1717828)?

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
$ cat > file.csv
"Product ID";"Product Name";"Price";"Description";
"11;"Example";"200";"Descripcion here...";
"21;"Example2";"300";"Some here...";
```

then

```
$ awk -F';' 'NR>1 {print "{" $0 "}" > substr($1,2) ".csv"}' file.csv
```

results in

```
$ head ??.csv
==> 11.csv <==
{"11;"Example";"200";"Descripcion here...";}

==> 21.csv <==
{"21;"Example2";"300";"Some here...";}
```

Comment: When i use this cmd in the original csv  giveme errors 
I add the csv file for test [csv file](http://petshopanimall.com/1.csv)

Comment: Well that differs in several ways from what you posted in your question - including DOS-style BOM and line endings, and different quoting of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F';' '{file=substr($1,2)".csv";if(NR>1){print $0 > file}}' inputFile
```

Use `substr` to get file name and append `.csv` to it, and `NR>1` to ignore header, and finally write to file.

```
$ head *csv

==> 11.csv <==
"11;"Example";"200";"Descripcion here...";

==> 21.csv <==
"21;"Example2";"300";"Some here...";
```

Comment: When i use this cmd in the original csv  giveme errors 
I add the csv file for test [csv file(http://petshopanimall.com/1.csv)